# Search a pattern in perl and print if number is greater than some value

Tags: regex, perl

Got multiple files in a log directory. Have to search for a string like `xyz:` and print a message if log contains a number greater than 3000.

```
Example 'xyz:40000/my'
```

Can some one suggest how to achieve it using regEx in perl.

```
if(/xyz:/)
{ 
  if(number next to xyz: is greater than 3000)
  { 
    print "Oh my god";
  }
}
```

I know it is an elementary question but I'm new to `perl regEx`. Any pointers would help

Answer (score 4):

You can try this snippet in a script run using `perl -n`:

```
if (/^xyz:([0-9]+)/)
{
    if ($1 > 3000)
    {
        print "Oh no!";
    }
}
```

You can also print the whole offending line printing just `$_` (or just `print`, that defaults to the current line). Or you can even accept the pattern to search for in each line in the command line, etc.

Comment: OP said "Got multiple files in a log directory", so one liner to search log: `cat grepped_txt | perl -n -e 'if (/^xyz:(\d+)/ && $1 > 3000) { print }'`